# What is the Path of the event created in CreateEvent

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am using CreateEvent to create an event in my Windows application. i want to know where under the object manage this event is created. from OSR online i found that it is under \BaseNamedObjects. can anyone confirm this ? i have used ObjDir to see the Event. but it is not under the \BaseNamedObjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are creating the event in the local session namespace so you'll likely find it in

```
\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects
```

Assuming that your interactive session is session 1.

```
\BaseNamedObjects
```

contains objects created in the global namespace.

Comment: From the command line you can search for it using [`accesschk`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) `-qost Event \ | findstr [name]`.

Comment: Event can be in other sessions if multiple users are logged in.